# List XML children elements names without their content using XPATH

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Consider this simple XML schema:

```
<products>
    <category name="furniture">
        <item name="chair">
            <size>
                <small>10</small>
                ...and many more
                <large>20</large>
            </size>
        </item>
    </category>
</products>
```

I'm looking to list the child elements of `<size>` without their actual content using XPATH.

```
$xml=simple_load_file('file.xml');

foreach ($xml->xpath("products/category[@=name'furniture']/item[@name='chair]/size") as $size)
     echo $size->????? . '<br>';
```

`$size->children();` outputs the actual text as such:

```
10
20
```

I'm looking for the following output:

```
small
...rest of elements
large
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in you Xpath expression. The first = is in the wrong position and the chair string is missing the closing quote. Adding `/*` You can select the child nodes of size directly.

```
/products/category[@name='furniture']/item[@name='chair']/size/*
```

Full source using DOMDocument:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
  <products>
    <category name="furniture">
        <item name="chair">
            <size>
                <small>10</small>
                <large>20</large>
            </size>
        </item>
    </category>
  </products>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate("/products/category[@name='furniture']/item[@name='chair']/size/*");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  echo $node->localName, "\n";
}
```